# Prevent string data from being padded with spaces from the left

Tags: vb6

I have an input box that I use to enter a alphanumeric account numbers in a database. The box accepts up to 25 characters. However, for data entry, each account number may not be as long as 25 characters. In such a case, the account numbers are saved with blank spaces before it instead of being saved to the left of the column. How can I solve this?

[image]

I would like each number to be saved like the two hyphenated numbers and not with a space like the first record.

Code summary:

```
Set objDB = New db.Detail_Data 
objDB.ConnectionString = CONNECTSTRING 
With objDB 
    .summary_code = CDbl(mvarSumcode) 
    .charge_code = UCase$(Me.txtChargeCode) 
    .clientID = UCase$(Me.txtClientID) 
    .JobID = UCase$(Me.txtJobID) 
    .Invno = UCase$(Me.txtInvno.Text) 
    .TransAmt = CCur(Me.txtTransAmt) 
    .Gl_accno = Format(Me.txtGL, "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@") 
    .Description = Me.txtDescription 
    blnStatus = .AddDetail
End With
```

Comment: Is there any code (short and to the point) that you can share to help answer this question? What you've done here is shown the mechanic a picture of your car, asking him to fix an issue with the engine.

Comment: @C-Pound Guru Please see code code above. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it works as coded. Your line:

```
.Gl_accno = Format(Me.txtGL, "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
```

`Format` with the `@` symbol right justifies the string, filling in spaces on the left. Unless you add a `!` like so ([source](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/using-format-function-custom-string-formats)).

```
.Gl_accno = Format(Me.txtGL, "!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
```